# Arch Linux not booting (Maybe related to not having left space for root)

Tags: linux, operating-system, filesystems, root, arch

I commited an error during my Arch Linux install that I don't know how to remedy, so I just sticked with it these months. I gave just ~35GB of storage space for the root partition.

This caused that for the last few months my PC have been warning about low space left in the root partition, but it was always of about ~400 MB, so I just ignored my problems thinking they would go away.

Today, I tried to boot Arch Linux, it goes all normal until the file system is started. It then leaves me with an unblinking selector in a black screen.

The output after that is exactly like this:

```
_
```

I cannot open a terminal with Ctrl + Alt + F1..F6, and I can't do anything.

I assume that this is happening because there is no space left in the root partition (Maybe the file system crashes), is that right? If it is, how could I increase the root partition space without having access to Arch Linux? Would reinstalling Arch Linux solve the problem?

This is my fault, I should have been more careful

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do in your situation:

- Make a bootable USB with Balena Etcher
- Boot from the USB
- Run `lsblk` and `df -h` to get more information about your storage devices

If your old root partition is (almost) full, you can mount it from your Live USB environment and make some space.

You can also consider [moving your home directory to a separate partition.](https://www.tecmint.com/convert-home-directory-partition-linux/)